# Начать программировать

Tags: веб-программирование, скрипт, сетевое-программирование

Всем привет, подскажите как начать программировать и учиться прямо на исходниках? Интересует Powershell и web.. Пробовал осилить github но там все проекты как-бы собраны в готовую программу и уровень мягко скажем не для начинающих

Comment: как стать хирургом, но сразу на практике, хочу сразу ассистентом на операцию, в какую клинику обратиться, где так можно?

Comment: вооружитесь книгами и их читайте. там материал структурирован и приспособлен для последовательного обучения. Один хрен правда без комплексного подхода результата хорошего не будет.

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос слишком общий для SO и вероятно будет закрыт.

Вообще есть много способов научится программировать (в том числе веб):

1. Видеоуроки,
2. Книги,
3. Видео с конференций,
4. Оффлайн и онлайн курсы,
5. Стажировки,
6. Статьи,
7. Работа с минимальной оплатой,
8. Туториалы (гайды) шаг за шагом,

У каждого свои предпочтения для обучения, то что идеально для одного (например, прохождение пошаговых заданий для чайников), может не дать никаких результатов для другого.

Но я советовал начать с конца. **Зачем вам нужно научится программировать? Что вы хотите получить в итоге?**

1. Хотите устроиться на работу? Ищите вакансии для начинающих в своем городе, смотрите требования и подтягивайте конкретные технологии.
2. Хотите зарабатывать фрилансом? Ищите простые проекты и пытайтесь их сделать для себя (пусть долго и без оплаты), но зато поймете каких знаний для них вам не хватает.

Когда у вас будет четкая цель "хочу работу в фирме X на позиции Y" и четкие шаги "мне нужно изучить N, M и Z", учится будет легче.

Comment: Мотивирующий ответ)

Answer (score 3):

Есть два пути

1. Пойти учиться в профильный ВУЗ. Внезапно, да?
2. найти реальную задачу и решить ее. Потом найти задачу посложнее и тоже решить ее. И так далее. В процессе решения изучать документацию, читать книги по основам, смотреть чужие реализации, задавать вопросы на stackoverflow...

Teran вам очень правильную аналогию про хирурга привел. Нельзя пройти курсы "C++ за пять дней" и стать программистом. Это достаточно сложная специальность, требующая длительного обучения и постоянного самосовершенствования. И чем раньше вы избавитесь от иллюзии, что "щас пол годика сайтики попишу и стану мега-востребованным спецом за сто тыщ мильёнов денег", тем быстрее научитесь.